# Help me identify this IC

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification

My kids got a Talking Tom toy in a kids meal which they quickly discarded. It had a slide switch on the back and a button on his belly. With the switch on, if you press the button, he will say one of 4 phrases. Also, if you clap or talk loudly, he will say one of 4 phrases. I decided to take it apart to see how it works. I've included a photo of the entire circuit - minus the metal strips that were used as switching devices. It's two button cell batteries, an IC with 5 pins, and a speaker. I'm curious what kind of IC this is? It has markings on one side that read: 66-EE GA1E. I couldn't find any reference on those markings.

The pin that is sticking up in the photo is the pin that was 'activated' by pushing the button on the toys belly. When touched to the positive lead from the battery, it'll speak. I suspect that the speaker acts as a trigger (for loud noises). Does anyone happen to know what kind of IC this is?

[image: toy circuit]

Comment: Probably it is some custom product-specific IC, not something you can find on the shelves.

Comment: Best to contact the manufacturer of the toy as they are probably the only ones with the info. It probably comes out of china maybe factory searching might yield a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's some application-specific integrated circuit (ASIC), designed to work in musical greeting cards, toys and the like. I doubt that you'll be able to find much information on that specific one, let alone a datasheet.

It most likely contains nothing but a [RC oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_oscillator) for timing, a [mask ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_ROM) programmed at the chip fab with the client-specific audio data, a rudimentary trigger circuit for the sound activation and some control logic to tie it all together.

I don't think that it contains a microprocessor, a "proper" digital-to-analog converter or that it stores [PCM audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation), as that would be unnecessarily complicated (more complicated -> more chip area -> more expensive). My guess is that the audio data is stored as an already [pulse density modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-density_modulation) bitstream, which is simply output one bit at a time to the speaker driver without any low pass filtering other than the speaker itself.

[image]

Comment: A lot of them these days are OTP (one-time programmable) for  fast turnaround. Sometimes flash.